# NativeScript page-router-outlet always taking up 100% height on iOS when used with RadSideDrawer

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

When using the RadSideDrawer with a page-router-outlet in NativeScript, it seems that there is no way to not have the page-router-outlet fill 100% of the height on iOS. On Android, it works fine. The reason I'm running into this issue is because I'm trying to add a BottomNavigationBar below my router outlet. The images below show the behavior on both iOS and Android:

[image: iOS]

[image: Android]

Here is my code:

```
<RadSideDrawer>
    <FlexboxLayout tkDrawerContent>
        <Button text="Test"></Button>
    </FlexboxLayout>
    <GridLayout class="main-grid" tkMainContent rows="*, auto">
        <StackLayout row="0">
            <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
        </StackLayout>
        <BottomNavigationBar activeColor="white" inactiveColor="gray" backgroundColor="black" row="1">
            <BottomNavigationTab title="First"></BottomNavigationTab>
            <BottomNavigationTab title="Second"></BottomNavigationTab>
            <BottomNavigationTab title="Third"></BottomNavigationTab>
        </BottomNavigationBar>
    </GridLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

If I remove the page-router-outlet and put anything in it's place, it will then function correctly on both iOS and Android. Also, if I leave the page-router-outlet and remove the RadSideDrawer, it also functions correctly.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT:
It seems as if this issue only occurs when there are two page-router-outlets nested as in this sample playground:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Z2a5Z7

Maybe page-router-outlets aren't supposed to be nested then? Right now I have a page-router-outlet in my app.component that lazy loads and switches between a login.component and my main app pages.component. pages.component contains the RadSideDrawer and the other page-router-outlet. I did this so I can lazy load my authorization pages and regular app content pages. Is this wrong?

Comment: Try setting a fixed height on BottomNavigationBar.

Comment: @Manoj Thought this might work but it didn't. I also tried setting a fixed height for the StackLayout around the page-router-outlet and this didn't work either :/

Comment: Can you share a sample project?

Comment: @Manoj sure, I added it to the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a issue with RadSideDrawer plugin (v8.0.0), the plugin is not open sourced so the best approach would be raising an issue in [nativescript-ui-feedback](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues) and I see you have done that already - [#1362](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/1362).

I have a workaround that seem to fix the issue on my end.

**MainComponent**

```
constructor(page: Page) {
    page.once(Page.navigatedToEvent, () => {
        page.frame.requestLayout();
    });
}
```

Request for relayout once the page is loaded.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Z2a5Z7&v=2)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have a modal page full height width over the side drawer, so I created a structure like below. Hope this helps you.

```
<GridLayout rows="" columns="" [class.dialogOpen]="dialogOpen">
  <StackLayout>
    <RadSideDrawer tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton drawerContentSize="320">
      <StackLayout tkDrawerContent>
        <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
        // my side drawer data
      </StackLayout>
      <GridLayout tkMainContent class="app" rows="auto,*,auto">
        <GridLayout row="0" columns="*" rows="auto,auto" *ngIf="data.navbar" class="gradient">
          // custom header
        </GridLayout>
        <!-- main content -->
        <FlexboxLayout row="1">
          <StackLayout #container>
            <StackLayout [ngClass]="{'full': data.full }">
              <ng-content></ng-content>
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
        </FlexboxLayout>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <FlexboxLayout row="2" *ngIf="data.footer" class="app__footer" verticalAlignment="bottom">
          // bottom tabs for my app
        </FlexboxLayout>
      </GridLayout>
    </RadSideDrawer>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" height="100%" class="dialog__wrapper">
    <AbsoluteLayout height="100%" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center">
      <!-- EDIT POPUP -->
      <StackLayout class="dialog__container">
        // cusotm dialog data
      </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem, but it did show me how to create a full page modal so thanks for that!